# react Async and setting state

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I have a total set in my state, initialized to 0.

Here is the function (in is triggered with an input field that gives it the qty parameter in another component):

```
calculateTotal(qty) {
  if (qty === 1) {
    this.setState({
      total: this.state.total += 250
    })
  }
  else if (qty > 1) {
    this.setState({
      total: qty *= 250
    })
  }
  else {
    this.setState({total: this.state.total})
  }
  console.log(this.state.total);
}
```

Comment: What is that bizarre output you get?

Comment: No. The quantity needs to be multiplied by 250.

Comment: this.state.total += 250 is actually "this.state.total = this.state.total + 250". Why are you mutating the original value instead of updating 'total' via setState?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are calling `setState`, I'm assuming that your code represents one method of some larger component.

`setState` is an asynchronous operation so your `console.log` is probably being called before the component state has been updated. However, if you try to `console.log` in the component's `render` method, you'll get more predictable results.

Since you should use `setState` to update your state and not mutate it directly, you should not do this:

```
this.state.total += 250
```

This tries to directly update `total`, effectively trying to bypass `setState`. You normally want to do something like this instead:

```
this.setState({
  total: this.state.total + 250
})
```

However, this is also incorrect because you want to calculate a new state based on a previous state. To be guaranteed to get the previous state ([due to the asynchronous nature of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)) you should do this instead:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    total: prevState.total + 250
  }
})
```

Also, `this.setState({total: this.state.total})` is not necessary. If you do not want to change the state, simply do nothing.

Finally, when the component's state has been updated, the React framework will then re-render your component. Therefore, try to log `total` in your component's `render` method. You should then get the values you expect.

Comment: Great answer. Just a style suggestion, your last snippet can be simplified to `this.setState(prevState => ({ total: prevState.total + 250 }))`

Comment: Totally. For "ES6-ophiles," this is the best syntax! :) <3 ... however, I wanted to show the longer form for clarity. Thanks for showing the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For one you only have to call setState once. Also setState is asynchronous as you stated along with the console log so in order to ensure the log is running after you set the state utilize a callback with setstate

```
calculateTotal(qty) {
  var total;
  if (qty === 1) {
    total = this.state.total + 250; // total = total + 250
  }
  else if (qty > 1) {
    total = (qty * 250);  // total = qty * 250
  }
  else {
    total = this.state.total;
  }
  this.setState({ total }, () => console.log(this.state.total))
}
```

Comment: Hi there, this reached the output I wanted however it only outputs the previous calculation, perhaps it needs to be in a component did mount?

Comment: @TomK Not sure you would have to provide additional code to clarify. Maybe mimic the problem utilizing a react fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/